# C#で作ったCOM内の配列要素にアクセスができない

Tags: c#, vba, com

Excel用のCOMをC#で作っております。

**Parameter.cs**

```CS
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IParameter))]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Parameter : IParameter
{
    public Member[] Members { get; set; }

    public Parameter()
    {
        Members = new Member[2];
        Members[0] = new Member(){ Name = "A"};
        Members[1] = new Member(){ Name = "B"};
        Members[2] = new Member(){ Name = "C"}
    }
}
```

**IParameter.cs**

```CS
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IParameter
{
    Member[] Members { get; set; }
}
```

VBA側でMemberクラスのインスタンスを生成する場合、以下のように記載

```vb
Dim param as Object
Set param = CreateObject("Parameter") ← 成功

Dim count as Integer
count = UBound(param.Members) ←countには2が入る
MsgBox param.Members(0).Name ←Error! 0番目の要素にアクセスできない
```

説明が長くなりましたが、上記でUBound(param.Members)では要素の数によって正しくUBound()の値が返ってきますが、各要素にアクセスしようとするとエラーになります。
エラーメッセージは以下の通りです。

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

どのようにすれば各要素にアクセスすることができるのでしょうか。

Comment: `Member`クラスor構造体の詳細や保持している値についても質問に追記してみてください。こちらの記事が似たような使い方の内容を扱っているようです。[COM Object Arrays From VB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40974978/9014308)

Answer (score 2):

VBにおけるUBoundは「個数」ではなく、「添え字の最大数」です。

元のC#のコードでは「new Member[2]」（要素数2）に対して、「Member[2] = ...」というように要素数3を期待しているコードがありますが、要素数はどちらでしょうか？

要素数2が正しく、LBoundが1であれば、添え字が1と2でアクセスできる2個の配列となっているのでしょう。ぜひ、LBoundも調べてみてください。

Comment: 要素数は3でUBound()実行時の戻り値が2(0,1,2)が返ってくることは理解できております。質問内容が分かりづらく申し訳ないのですが、質問内容としてはUBound(Members)で正しく2が返ってくるにも関わらず、いざ添字0(1つ目の要素)にアクセスしようとすると上記のエラーが発生し困っている状況です。

Comment: Azulean さんが述べられているのはVBの配列が「1始まりの場合もある」という意味だと思います。状況によって意図せず0始まり、1始まりどちらもあり得ます。1始まりの場合添え字0はエラーになるため、LBoundを調べてみては？ということでしょう。試しに添え字1でアクセスできるかやってみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: C#のコードの ` Members = new Member[2];` は誤りだったということで合っていますか？ビルドエラーになっているなど、事実誤認が起きていないかと気になりました。

Comment: Memberの定義は共有されていませんが、手元で実験する限り、KOZさんが提示されているVariantに一度代入をすれば、0～2でアクセスできましたので、そちらを試してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

試していませんが、param.Members をいったん Variant で受けるとうまくいくかもしれません。

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim m As Member
v = param.Members
For i = LBounds(v) To UBounds(v)
    Set m = v(i)
Next
```